# Open CV Project in Eclipse?

Tags: opencv

i am going to develop a project in Android, the project idea is: Camera will be open and it will recognize the string like email address, phone No, Address etc from a Business  card etc. I have already configured and install cygwin and have compile/Run many c++ programs in Eclipse, but now i want to know, that whether i should install Open CV(like OpenCV2.0) and include its file in C++ project, Or i should download the OpenCV SDK and include in my Android Project. plz help
 for example i have this code for displaying image using open cv, but i need to use CAMERA and then recongnize the pic

```
 #include "cv.h"
 #include "highgui.h"
//using namespace openCV2;
int main()//int argc, char *argv[])
{
  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("prado.jpg",1);
  cvNamedWindow( "Example1",1);
  cvShowImage("Example1", img );
  cvWaitKey(0);//*/

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want set project on android use opencv,
you have try to use opencv for android or opencv for windows,
opencv for android SDK using JAVA API,
opencv for windows SDK using C++ API.
I recommed to use JAVA API on android,
If you must use C++ API you can reference android NDK information.

Comment: thanks fro the great reply, i know about the open CV for windows using c++ code, i have done few starting programs in visual c++, but i don't know how to use JAVA API for OPEN CV in android, is it required some configuration of libraries etc in android environment like i was treat with it in VISUAL STUDIO,

Comment: It will be great for me if you tell me about that how to use JAVA API for OPEN CV in android environment. i am waiting for your assist.

Answer (score 1):

For image processing related operations in Android use the [OpenCV-Android-SDK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.9/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk.zip/download).

The SDK contains sample apps like Camera Preview, Face Recognition etc. along with the OpenCV-library need by android apps using OpenCV.

For integration with eclipse & other relevant information visit:

1. [OpenCV for Android](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html#get-the-opencv4android-sdk)
2. [Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Linux](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Linux-API11.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an already compiled project that is using openCV, the sample will get the rgb colors in real time.
[compiled opencv project for android](https://github.com/yoggy/ColorPickerCamera)